# How to replace first letter and last letter in array of strings

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to replace in the array of strings in EVERY word, the first letter with A and the last letter with Z

My Array :

```
String[] replaceFirstLetter1 = new String[]{"Java Bople Orange New Dog Cat"};
```

This is what I am trying:

```
  public static String[] replaceFirstLetterWithZ(String[] replaceFirstLetter) {
        String[] tempTable = new String[replaceFirstLetter.length];
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < replaceFirstLetter.length; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(replaceFirstLetter[i]);
            stringBuilder.replace(0, replaceFirstLetter.length, "A");
            stringBuilder.replace(replaceFirstLetter.length-1, replaceFirstLetter.length, "Z");
            tempTable[i] = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        return tempTable;
    }
```

Anyhow my output is not what I am expecting
Output:

```
[Zava Bople Orange New Dog Cat]
```

Can any of you give a hand on what  and where I should look for my mistake ?
Thanks

Comment: `replaceFirstLetter1` is an array with only one item. Maybe you are supposed to [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the string first.

Comment: What happens if a word is only a single letter?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  , that make totally sense , Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @Nexevis   , I assume that  it will not be taken into account ? :-/

Comment: Note that your array contains a single String - is that intended or do you expect the words in that String to be separate Strings?

Comment: @vsfDawg, How is it is  ok , Also the Answer from Bohemian is  correct   also from Nexevis :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is the goto tool here.

To replace the first and last characters of every word in a string with A and Z:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\w(\\w*)\\w", "A$1Z");
```

This works by matching words but capturing all characters of the word except the first and last characters, and replacing the match with A-group1-Z.

FYI words of only 1 letter are not matched.

To apply this to an array of String:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i].replaceAll("\\w(\\w*)\\w", "A$1Z");
}
```

---

It's possible to do it without regex using a `StringBuilder` and iterating through the characters looking for word boundaries - characters that have a non-letter before them or after them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        char c = sb.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            if (i == 0 || !Character.isLetter(sb.charAt(i - 1))) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, 'A');
            } else if (i == sb.length() - 1 || !Character.isLetter(sb.charAt(i + 1))) {
                sb.setCharAt(i, 'Z');
            }
        }
    }
    array[i] = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: That make sense now , 
Apparently I  got stuck with the `StringBuilder`  since it have the method to replace fist and last of the word .
Thank you for the information and support ,I  will have to look deeper intro the reggex + replace

Comment: Bohemian, is there any how to do it by string Builder?

Comment: @BecaNr1 Yes - see edited answer. Make sure you understand it before submitting it :)

Comment: I have done it this way Thanks  for the information :)
`public static String[] replaceFirstLetterWithZ(String[] table) {
        String[] tempTable = new String[table.length];
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
stringBuilder.append(table[i]);
stringBuilder.replace(0, 1, "A");
stringBuilder.replace(table[i].length() - 1, table[i].length(), "Z");
tempTable[i] = stringBuilder.toString();
stringBuilder.delete(0, table[i].length()); }
        return tempTable;}`

Answer (score 0):

Other than Regex that Bohemian mentioned (which is the norm for this kind of stuff), you can also do it manually by using `substring` to remove the first and last characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] arr = replaceFirstLetterWithZ("Java Bople Orange New A Dog Cat".split(" "));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

public static String[] replaceFirstLetterWithZ(String[] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].length() > 1) {
            arr[i] = "A" + arr[i].substring(1, arr[i].length() - 1) + "Z";
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

While using `substring`, you will need to be careful to not get an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so a check to make sure the size is greater than 1 is used, and if the `String` does not meet the requirement, no replacing is done.

For example, the letter `A` will not be replaced with anything because there are not two characters to replace.

Also notice the change to `String[] replaceFirstLetter1 = new String[]{"Java Bople Orange New Dog Cat"};` in the main, you need to `split` in order to break the `String` into an array.  The way you were doing it, the entire `String` was in the same array element.

**Output:**

```
[AavZ, AoplZ, ArangZ, AeZ, A, AoZ, AaZ]
```

Comment: This help also  :),   and I will still have a look to see how can I do this  using the `StringBuilder`  0:-)